# Absolute values in logarithms in a solution of differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, logarithms, absolute-value

How have the moduli signs disappeared in the following step:

$$\frac1{k}\left(\ln|g+kv| - \ln|g+ku|\right) = -t$$

Therefore
$$ \ln\left(\frac{g+kv}{g+ku}\right) = -kt$$

$g$, $k$ and $u$ are positive constants. $t$ is time, $v$ is velocity.

---

*Context*: the above calculations are from solving  the equation $dv/dt = -g - kv$ given that $v = u$ when $t = 0$, and that $u$, $g$ and $k$ are positive constants.

Comment: What is the context? perhaps the context is such that $g+kv$ and$g+ku$ have the same sign, in which case one can dispense with the modulus.

Comment: Is $v$ _velocity_ always non-negative?

Answer (score 1):

$g+kv$ need not be positive, but it will have the same sign as $g+ku$, because the solutions cannot cross the equilibrium at $v=-g/k$. Hence, the quotient inside the logarithm is positive.

Ideally, you would not arrive at $\frac1{k}\left(\ln|g+kv| - \ln|g+ku|\right) = -t$ at all; there is a cleaner way  of solving this ODE. Namely, one goes from 
  $\ln|g+kv|=-kt+C$ (with indefinite constant $C$) to $g+kv = Ae^{-kt}$, where $A$ takes the place of $\pm e^C$.

Answer (score 0):

If $k$, $g$, $u$ are all positive, you need to  have $v$ large enough (i.e., not too negative) to make $g + k v > 0$. Maybe that results from some part that you haven't told us...